# Find the number of four-letter words that use letters from {A, B, C} in which no three consecutive letters are the same.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Case 1: (3)(3)(2)(3)=54. In the first two spots the letters can be any of A,B, or C. The third spot is where we risk having a third consecutive letter, so there are only 2 choices. Now the fourth spot can be either of the three letters.

Case 2: (3)(2)(3)(3)=54. Similar to case 1, this is the only other way to prevent three consecutive letters from occurring.
So there are 54+54=108 different words. Please check if my reasoning makes sense.

Comment: there are $81$ words using letters $A, B, C$ so you cannot possibly be correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better approach is to discard cases that do not work from the total. There are a total of $3^4 = 81$ four-letter words with letters $A, B, C$. From these,

- $3$ words have only $1$ letter: $AAAA$, $BBBB$ and $CCCC$.
- Words with $3$ consecutive letters equal and one different: $3 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 = 12$; here, we first choose the letter that appears $3$ times, then a different letter to be the other one, and finally notice that either the group of $3$ starts or ends the word.

So, your answer should be: $81 - 3 - 12 = 66$.

Answer (score 2):

This is incorrect.  Remember that to apply rule of product, we require that the number of choices available at each step *does not depend on choices made in previous steps*.  Your decreasing the number of options by one in these positions in your attempts was contingent on a letter having been repeated which is not always going to happen.

As for a correct approach, it should be much easier to first count how many four letter words can be formed if we don't care, and then subtract the number of "bad" words that were possible (*taking special care to think about possibilities like $AAAA$*)